# Gulp - Changing error text color in Terminal with chalk

Tags: terminal, gulp, chalk

Here's my **gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var sass  = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var chalk = require('chalk');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('assets/scss/*.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
});
```

The error logging works, for example if I set an undefined variable in my Sass the terminal will show:

```
[13:31:23] Using gulpfile ~/Development/test/gulpfile.js
[13:31:23] Starting 'sass'...
[13:31:23] error assets/scss/style.scss (Line 3: Undefined variable: "$red".)
[13:31:23] Finished 'sass' after 248 ms
```

I have included [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) as I would like to change the color of the error in Terminal, but how would I go about doing that? I have tried:

```
.on('error', chalk.red(sass.logError))
```

But that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: It doesn't work because `chalk.red` is expecting a `string` but you're giving it a `function`. You could reimplement `sass.logError` if you feel like it...

Comment: Late to the party, but I'm not actually seeing where you're using Chalk in your first example. If you're at all still facing this issue, could you edit with a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

@kombucha is right, you can reimplement `sass.logError` and use `chalk.red` inside of that. After checking source code of `sass.logError` from https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/blob/master/index.js, the result would be like:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
...
.on('error', function() {
    var message = new gutil.PluginError('gulp-ruby-sass', err);
    console.error(chalk.red(message + '\n'));
    this.emit('end');
})
```